# How to increase an FS using a LiveCD - that has SW RAID+LVM

Tags: lvm, raid

If we have an older OS and can only increase the FS if we umount the FS because it is the ex.: /usr - then we have to use a LiveCD.

The /usr is in the rootvg (LVM) that is on a SW raid

**Q:** What are the steps after booting in a LiveCD to increase the LV then the FS ex.: by 1 GByte? (of course data gathering can be done on the running system before using the LiveCD)

UPDATE: the VolumeGroup has free space! So the SW doesn't need to be increased.

Comment: It's unclear what you want to resize—are you trying to resize just the filesystem + logical volume? Or are you trying to resize the RAID array and physical volume as well?